# Android - Webview truncates string

Tags: android, string, webview, truncated

I have a Webview where I am trying to show this string:

> "---*@%-@%%#:-=%@+=%-#@##%@%--.....-=.-=:-:.........=----::::::::=---:::::::::::::.............................................::::.........................................-*#+ ."

However, the string is truncated and displayed in more than one line, and I can't figure out why. It should be displayed in only one line. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

This is how I am populating the webview:

`web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

where s is the string previously showed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, for starters, that doesn't look like HTML to me... Have you considered specifying `text/plain` instead?

Comment: The problem with using text/plain is that my strings get wrapped. Is there anyway to avoid word-wrap in a webview when using text/plain?